# Error in Field Service Book Appointment

Tags: service, field-service-lightning

I have assigned a user "FSL Dispatcher" profile and trying to Book an Appointment via that user but on clicking on "Get Appointments" i am getting attempt to dereference a null object error.
Am i missing some permission or some records are missing which are required to get appointments.
When i am doing this via System Admin profile, i am not getting any error.

Comment: Without seeing your code, we probably can't do much more than speculate. Initial guess would be object visibility (e.g. querying for a record a normal user can't see), but it would really help if you could post some code that demonstrates what you believe to be the issue.

Comment: @sfdcfox Its a managed code installed as a part of Field Service Lightning Package provided by salesforce.

Comment: did you get it fixed? I am getting this error even for System Admin.

Answer (score -1):

See here.  Looks like Salesforce has a knowledge topic on the situation.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000264820&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: Can you [edit] this to include the relevant bits from the link? It might go dead in the future.